# How could I login by ftp from Emacs with elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have defined the following function with Emacs, I defined the "username" for a website and the associated "password". But, how could I make this function show a dired view of the ftp like it does when you login with the regular method ( /username@ftp.site.com:/ )

```
(defun myftp_login()
  "Login to a ftp"
  ( ange-ftp-set-user "ftp.site.com" "username" )
  ( ange-ftp-set-passwd "ftp.site.com" "username" "password" )
  ;; command to open dired view to a folder in ftp.site.com
 )
```

I already searched for similar questions but I couldn't find one that solves my problem, thank you.

---

**solution:**
As Tobias and Michael Albinus pointed out, the code should look like this and the passwords should be stored in ~/.netrc for safer storage:

```
(defun ftplogin_site()
  "Login to the ftp.site.com"
  (interactive)
  ( ange-ftp-set-user "ftp.site.com" "username" )
  ( find-file "/username@ftp.site.com:/folder/folder/")
 )
```

Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: Did you try `(find-file "/username@ftp.site.com:/")`?

Comment: Works like a charm! Can you post this as an aswer instead of a comment so I can mark it as the right solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(find-file "/username@ftp.site.com:/")`.

The best first place to dig is often the key-binding. The key combination <kbd>C-h k</kbd> <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> reveals `find-file`.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to find where to get that kind of info,  I tried C-h f with the ange-ftp functions.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to touch ange-ftp variables. Open a file like `C-x C-f /ftp:username@ftp.site.com:/`

Comment: That won't work on elisp, that's ok to manually login to an ftp but I need to create a program in elisp to automate that login.

Comment: `(find-file "/ftp:username@ftp.site.com:/")`

The password shall be set in `~/.netrc`, or you use a mechanism of `auth-source.el` for passing the password. If it isn't provided, the password will be asked for interactively.